# Want to count input length, and when below 6 show an error

Tags: javascript, html, input, count, string-length

```
function validateWieslid() {

var countnummer = $("nummer").val().length;
var countpin = $("pin").val().length;

if (countnummer.length < 6) { 
    document.getElementById("lrError").innerHTML = " Lidnummer moet 6 cijfers lang zijn.";
    document.getElementById("lrError").style.backgroundColor = "red";
 } 
if (countpin.length < 4) { 
    document.getElementById("pinError").innerHTML = " Pin moet 4 cijfers lang zijn.";
    document.getElementById("pinError").style.backgroundColor = "red";
 } 
}
```

That is my JavaScript function

```
            <div id="wies">
                <label>Lidnummer:</label> 
                <input name="lidnummer" size="30" type="text" id="nummer" maxlength="6"><br>
                <label>WIES pin:</label> 
                <input name="pin" size="30" type="text" id="pin" maxlength="4"><br>
           </div>

     <div id="lrError"></div>
     <div id="pinError"></div>
```

That is my HTML code in question,

The input with id="nummer" is supposed to be a 6 character long input, the input with id="pin" is supposed to be a pin number so its 4 characters long.

I'm trying to make it so that it shows the text shown in the JavaScript when the input length is below 6, however this I cannot make this work? I'm a beginning coder and this might be a really easy solution, but I'd like some assistance! Thanks :)

Comment: You have already saved the length at `$("nummer").val().length;`. You don't have to rewrite `.length` after: `countnummer.length < 6`. Just do `countnemmer <6 ...`

Comment: Anyway, use Firebug or other to debug your code. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle to remove the jquery dependency

http://jsfiddle.net/SJJvk/2/

```
function validateWieslid() {
var countnummer = document.getElementById("nummer").value.length;
var countpin = document.getElementById("pin").value.length;

if (countnummer < 6) { 
  document.getElementById("lrError").innerHTML = " Lidnummer moet 6 cijfers lang zijn.";
  document.getElementById("lrError").style.backgroundColor = "red";
} 
if (countpin < 4) { 
  document.getElementById("pinError").innerHTML = " Pin moet 4 cijfers lang zijn.";
  document.getElementById("pinError").style.backgroundColor = "red";
 } 
}
```

### BELOW IS NOW DEPRECATED:

There were a couple of issues with your code.

Here is a jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SJJvk/

1) you were not triggering your function.
2) You were missing the # from your jQuery calling the error divs
3) your variables are actual numbers, no need to test for length,

```
function validateWieslid() {
var countnummer = $("#nummer").val().length;
var countpin = $("#pin").val().length;
console.log("cn is " + countnummer);
console.log("cn is " + countpin);

if (countnummer < 6) { 
document.getElementById("lrError").innerHTML = " Lidnummer moet 6 cijfers lang zijn.";
document.getElementById("lrError").style.backgroundColor = "red";
} 
if (countpin < 4) { 
document.getElementById("pinError").innerHTML = " Pin moet 4 cijfers lang zijn.";
document.getElementById("pinError").style.backgroundColor = "red";
} 
}
```

Comment: @user2891807 kindly accept one of our answers, preferably mine. :-D

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly in the jsFiddle, but somehow it wont work in my code. Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: Have you imported jquery into your page?

If not ...add something like the following to the top of your page.

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

NOTE: the script is missing http://  .... you must add that after " and before code.

please visit http://jquery.com/download/ to see example

Also...what browser are you using? If please search on developer tools for your browser type to learn how to open the javascript console....this would have immediately exposed your issues to you.

Comment: I did not have that code on the top of my page, but even without that my other JavaScript code I implemented to the website did work without a problem. 

Ofcourse I did add the .js source in the header.

PS± Even after adding the Jquery line to my code it did not seem to work.

Oh and Im using Google Chrome

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to remove jquery dependency
http://jsfiddle.net/SJJvk/2/

When using Chrome, right click on page, select "inspect element" and then click the "console" tab a top right...this will show your javascript output.

Comment: Oh man, it´s still not working.. And the console tab isnt showing any output either, I checked the settings and it seems to be fine.

Comment: Oh man....there is just all kinds of wrong with that page beside just your basic question which you have asked. If I have time tonight, I will try to dig into it deeper.

Comment: I know that there's probably alot that is wrong or could be done better, I'm a first year student on Informatics and this is our first HTML assignment/project of the year... it does not have to be perfect, as long as it works, and right now everything except for the function in the question is working. If you really want to dive deeper into the page I'd appreciate it, but it's not neccesary.. all I need is the function to work. 

Thanks a lot for your help though, you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

For accessing the elements from their Id you should use # before the id name. For example for accessing following element -

```
<input name="lidnummer" size="30" type="text" id="nummer" maxlength="6">
```

I will use

```
$("#nummer")
```

First two lines of the method `validateWieslid()` will not work. It should be -

```
var countnummer = $("#nummer").val().length;
var countpin = $("#pin").val().length;
```

The correct code will be -

```
function validateWieslid() {
var countnummer = $("#nummer").val().length;
var countpin = $("#pin").val().length;
var flag = true;
if (countnummer < 6) { 
    document.getElementById("lrError").innerHTML = " Lidnummer moet 6 cijfers lang zijn.";
    document.getElementById("lrError").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    flag = false;
 } 
if (countpin < 4) { 
    document.getElementById("pinError").innerHTML = " Pin moet 4 cijfers lang zijn.";
    document.getElementById("pinError").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    flag = false;
 } 
 return flag;
}
```

And suppose your HTML code is-

```
   <div id="wies">
        <form id="myForm" action="">
        <label>Lidnummer:</label> 
        <input name="lidnummer" size="30" type="text" id="nummer" maxlength="6"><br>
        <label>WIES pin:</label> 
        <input name="pin" size="30" type="text" id="pin" maxlength="4"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
   </div>
```

Now you can bind the function with the form submit event by using -

```
$("#myForm").submit(function( event ) {
  if(!validateWieslid())
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This solution omits the fact that he also needs to trigger the function

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortuantely it´s still not working.

This demo includes your information± http://jsfiddle.net/AZKyn/28/

Comment: @user2891807 You have not enclosed the elements within the form tag.

Comment: Your problem now is the configuration of the fiddle.....please compare to mine (which works) below.  

You must select a version of jquery and set no wrap body in the options

Comment: I'm trying to give the correct answer...which so far no one (besides me) has.....

Here is your fiddle...now fixed.
http://jsfiddle.net/AZKyn/29/